# Tensorflow DNNRegressor Multiple Outputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to use `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor` to model a multi-input multi-output system. I have followed the [Boston DNNRegressor example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/input_fn/) on the Tensorflow website, however when I try to pass an array of 2 outputs to the regressor fitter, I get

```
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (100, 1) and (100, 2) are incompatible
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893114/tensorflow-multivariate-dnnregressor) with no responses from back in January, so it seems other people have had this problem.

I could conceivably use multiple DNNRegressors for each of the outputs, however is it possible to predict multiple outputs with a single `DNNRegressor` in Tensorflow?

I am running Tensorflow 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more than a little too late, but the current `tf.estimator.DNNRegressor` has an argument `label_dimension` that might do what you're looking for.

```
regressor = estimator.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=my_feature_columns,
                                   label_dimension=2,
                                   hidden_units=hidden_layers,
                                   model_dir=MODEL_PATH)
```

In my case this deals perfectly with two outputs